# how to make four Condition Disabled Enabled button

Tags: javascript, html

how to make four Condition Disabled Enabled button. function not working.

```js
    function testcheckall() {
    if (/^[ก-๙]+$/.test(document.getElementById("firstname").value && /^[ก-๙]+$/.test(document.getElementById("lastname").value) && /^0[689][0-9]{8}$/.test(document.getElementById("mobile").value) && /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/.test(document.getElementById("email").value))) {
      document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
          }else{
          document.getElementById("send").disabled = true;
          }
        }
```

Comment: what you want to fix?

Comment: sorry function not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you messed up the parenthesis in the condition expression, you're missing a parenthesis after the first reges check

```
 function testcheckall() {

if (/^[ก-๙]+$/.test(document.getElementById("firstname").value) && 
    /^[ก-๙]+$/.test(document.getElementById("lastname").value) && 
    /^0[689][0-9]{8}$/.test(document.getElementById("mobile").value) && 
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/.test(document.getElementById("email").value)) {
      document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
          }else{
          document.getElementById("send").disabled = true;
          }
        }
```

Comment: you're very welcome! just tag it as the correct answer!